# Npm error in configuring tailwind css using cli "npx tailwindcss init"

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

PS C:\Users\hp\Documents\Coding\Tailwind\Tailwind_First_Class> npx tailwindcss init
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-22T14_24_06_150Z-debug-0.log